# SVM one versus one

Tags: matlab, svm

I want to use svm one versus one to improve the test accuracy. But I have a problem about writing it. I have 191 items and 7 classes with each label, and feature matrix whose size is 3024*191. I think I need to make svmtrain 7*6/2 times to complete, but I cannot image how to do that. Can someone give me some examples. Thanks.

Comment: Are we seeing a flood of `SVM` related homeworks today on [MATLAB tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab)? Or is a there new breakthrough in this field waiting to happen?

Comment: Use a loop? also you might find `nchoosek(1:7,2)` useful...